# Error with "swift build" in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: swift, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, nsregularexpression

I have a problem when I tried to compile a Swift code, I believe that it's something about Swift in Ubuntu. Here is the error:

```
swift build
```

`Compiling Swift Module 'testregex' (1 sources)` `/home/guillermo/Descargas/Hola/Sources/testregex.swift:4:1: error: statements are not allowed at the top level` 
`if let range = str.rangeOfString("string$", options: .RegularExpressionSearch) { ^` 
`<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures`

```
error: exit(1): ["/home/guillermo/Descargas/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-01-25-a-ubuntu14.04/usr/bin/swift-build-tool", "-f", "/home/guillermo/Descargas/Hola/.build/debug/testregex.o/llbuild.yaml"]
```

If somebody know how to solve this weird problem, I'll be very greatful
:)

Comment: Please show the relevant code.

Comment: import Foundation
 
let str = "I am a string"
if let range = str.rangeOfString("string$", options: .RegularExpressionSearch) {
  print("Ends with 'string'")
}

Comment: but, i put a simple print("hello world"), and display the same error

Comment: I think I found the explanation, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `swift build` expects to find a `main.swift` file in the `Sources` folder.

Rename your `testregex.swift` file to `main.swift` and it will build properly.

You can have as many `.swift` files as you want in the Sources folder, but there has to be one `main.swift` file.

Comment: ok, now i have this error when i put swift build                                      Linking Hola3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crtbegin.o:                                                            No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
<unknown>:0: error: link command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures
in addition to the above error

Comment: yes, that solve the first error, but now i have another, that say /usr/bin/ld: cannot find crtbegin.o: No such file or directory, and i dont know how to solve it, 
and thanks for solving the first error :D